# Acts 3:2, 10 What is the Beautiful Gate?

Tags: acts

In Acts 3 we can read about some place in the temple being refereed to as; The gate of the temple which is called Beautiful Acts 3:2 and; the Beautiful Gate of the temple Acts 3:10

> And a man who had been unable to walk from birth was being carried,
> whom they used to set down every day at the gate of the temple which
> is called Beautiful, in order for him to beg for charitable gifts from
> those entering the temple grounds. [Acts 3:2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%203%3A2&version=NASB;KJV)

> 10 and they recognized him as being the very one who used to sit at
> the Beautiful Gate of the temple to beg for charitable gifts, and they
> were filled with wonder and amazement at what had happened to him. [Acts 3:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts+3%3A10&version=NASB;KJV)

Fair, beautiful ωραιαν [G5611](https://saintebible.com/greek/5611.htm)

What gate is this? Is it within the temple as the text imply "gate of the temple" makes it sound it is between the inner court / the court of the women, or the court of the women / the outer court or is't one of The Walls of Jerusalem surrounds the Old City, the Golden Gate, Jaffa Gate etc?

Answer (score 3):

The gate of the temple that best fit this description was the Gate of Nicanor, going from the Court of the Gentiles to the Court of the Women.

Figure 1. The Temple Gate of Nicanor (From BiblePlaces.com image library)
[image]

> **Beautiful** (ὡραιαν [Hōraian]). This gate is not so called elsewhere. It may have been the Gate of Nicanor on the east side looking towards Kidron described by Josephus (Ant. XV. 11, 3; War V. 5, 3) as composed chiefly of Corinthian brass and very magnificent.
> --
> Robertson, A. T. (1933). *Word Pictures in the New Testament* (Ac 3:2). Broadman Press.

> 3:2–3. The “Beautiful Gate” was probably a popular title for the Nicanor Gate (named for its Alexandrian donor), the main and largest gate, made of the most expensive bronze. It was in the Court of the Women on the east, facing the gate of the sanctuary, and must have been especially beautiful in the light of the rising sun. Situated above fifteen steps, beyond which neither women nor the maimed and unclean could pass, it may have hosted beggars on its steps who could appeal to those going to the Court of Israel.
> --
> Keener, C. S. (1993). *The IVP Bible background commentary: New Testament* (Ac 3:2-3). InterVarsity Press.

> 3:2. The description of a man crippled from birth emphasizes his hopeless condition. He was more than 40 years old (4:22). People carried him every day to the temple gate named Beautiful so that he could beg. This may have been the eastern gate of the temple area that led from the court of the Gentiles into the women’s court.
> --
> Toussaint, S. D. (1985). Acts. In J. F. Walvoord & R. B. Zuck (Eds.), *The Bible Knowledge Commentary: An Exposition of the Scriptures* (Vol. 2, p. 360). Victor Books.

Comment: thanks Perry for your contribution. When I watch other pictures they have Gate of Nicanor and The Beautiful Gate as the first gate; https://www.refreshinghope.org/public/album_photo/24/34/02/852ef49b82b0c8cc525ce61d37cc3358.png